docker hangs at build
docker blocks when running the command:
docker-compose build nginx php-fpm workspace mysql redis redis-webui adminer;

gives the the following error:
CACHED [workspace 50/116] RUN if [ false = true ]; then if [ 8.3 != "8.3" ] && [ 8.3 != "8.0" ];  then curl -L -o /tmp/ioncube_loaders_lin 0.0s
CACHED [workspace 51/116]  RUN if [ false = true ]; then apt-get -y install mysql-client && curl https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console-1 0.0s
CANCELED[workspace 52/116] RUN if [ true = true ]; then mkdir -p /home/laradock/.nvm && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/ 228.0s

does anyone know what is the cause? I use laravel and laradock.

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

Also make sure to include a [mcve] – on its own the error message often isn't enough to debug an issue.

I think it might be a network issue. I suggest checking network connectivity from the host where you are building your containers:
curl -I https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/


Also, it always a good idea to add some retry logic to the curl command, like this:
curl --retry 5 --max-time 30 -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/

and when you will rebuild your images, you can add more verbose logging, by add --verbose option, like this:
docker-compose --verbose build nginx php-fpm workspace mysql redis redis-webui adminer


i get this message when i run curl command:
$ curl --retry 5 --max-time 30 -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15916  100 15916    0     0  88978      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 89920
=> nvm is already installed in /c/Users/ovy79/.nvm, trying to update using git
=> => Compressing and cleaning up git repository

=> Profile not found. Tried ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zprofile, ~/.zshrc, and ~/.profile.
=> Create one of them and run this script again
   OR
=> Append the following lines to the correct file yourself:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\ovy79\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ovy79\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ovy79\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-23T08_54_20_113Z-debug-0.log
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

